# Year to Date SQL with criteria

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have the following table:

```
oDate        value
------------------------
2017-01-01   10
2017-01-10   10
2017-02-04   20
2017-03-01   10
2017-03-06   30
2017-04-10   40
```

I want to have the total for all date by month. So the query should be:

```
select datepart(month, oDate) month, SUM(value) TotalValue
from myTable
group by datepart(month, oDate)
```

If I want to have the total for all value, I just need to skip the `group by` section and remove the `datepart(month, oDate)`.

I have 2 parameters which is `@Month int` and `@Year varchar(5)`.
The question is: I want to add some calculation in the selected `month` and `year`.

For example, if the parameter for `@Month <= 3` and `@Year <= '2017'` then the total is `(Jan/2017 TotalValue) + (Feb/2017 TotalValue) + (Mar/2017 TotalValue)`.

But, If the parameter for `@Month > 3` and `@Year = '2017'` then the total is `(Jan/2017 TotalValue) + (Feb/2017 TotalValue) + (Mar/2017 TotalValue) + (Apr/2017 TotalValue * 2)`.

Sample result:
With 1st criteria (@Month <= 3 and @Year <= '2017')

```
TotalValue
------------
70
```

With 2nd criteria (@Month > 3 and @Year >= '2017')

```
TotalValue
-----------
150
```

In the 2nd criteria, the total on Apr/2017 is multiple by `2`. So `40 * 2 = 80`. Total Value from Jan/2017 until Mar/2017 is `70` then the Year to Date for 2nd criteria is `70 + 80 = 150`.

Is there a way to do it?
Please advise, cheers.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and sample results, it's not clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Why multiplying `April` by 2? And if `@month > 3` why do you sum also months that are `<=3` ???

Comment: @JeffUK, done. Hope that help to understand my question.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, for some reason mate. :)

Comment: I think you're just going to need a lot of CASE statements..  What happens when you have data for May and June?

Comment: With such clear explanation, I doubt that anyone will help...

Comment: @jeffUK, its the same with april. After march, the total for each month will be multiplied by 2.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: @MichałTurczyn, check the answer below. :)

Comment: @HABO, Thank you so much. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this simple sample, here is how you would do it. Also, according to your test data, your value is wrong. Jan - March totals are 80, not 70.

```
declare @table table (oDate date, [value] int)
insert into @table
values
('20170101',10),
('20170110',10),
('20170204',20),
('20170301',10),
('20170306',30),
('20170410',40)

declare @Month int = 4       --change this to 3, or 2, or 1...
declare @Year int = 2017

select 
    --[Month] = datepart(month, oDate), 
    TotalValue = SUM(case when datepart(month, oDate) <= 3 then [value] else [value] * 2 end) 
from 
    @table
where
    datepart(year,oDate) = @Year
    and datepart(month, oDate) <= @Month
--group by 
--  datepart(month, oDate)
```